# Class as user defined data type

Tags: java

I know that a class can be considered as an user defined data type because it is based on fundamental data types.But consider the snippet

```
class dog
{
   public void bark()
   {
     System.out.println("bhow bhow");
   }
}
```

this class doesn't contain any primitive variable.So how can this be a user defined data type?
I am really confused. :(

Comment: A class can also contain methods, which perform actions. Your `bark` method is an example of this.

Comment: but a method is not a primitive data type

Comment: There is some primitive data there. You print a String, "bhow bhow". Which can be considered an array of char.

Comment: You are a person but you don't contain another person (as far as I know ;-), but that doesn't stop you being a person... `dog isA data type` - you can create an instance of a dog and make it bark - doesn't matter how it is implemented internally.

Comment: But my book says that it should contain primitive data types as a composite data type is based on primitives

Comment: Your question doesn't mention composite data types...

Comment: ain't a user defined data type and composite data type the same?@John3136

Answer (score 1):

Whether a class contains a primitive data type or not has no bearing on whether or not it is considered a User-Defined Type.

You defined `class dog`, did you not?

Answer (score 1):

The key word in your question is "can". A very basic class can be thought of as a user defined type. If you are equating a UDT to a structure in languages such as C then this will be a class with public fields and little else.

But in Java a class is more than a UDT, I suggest you do some more research in to what a class in Java is.

Also you may want to consider trying to stick to the Java coding conventions.

Comment: So what more is it? Can you give me some references for my research?

Answer (score 0):

Think of a class as a noun and a verb.

```
public class dog
```

is the noun

```
System.out.println()
```

is the verb